# mesos slave failed to excute docker command

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker, mesos, marathon

when i start a docker containner on mesos-slave

the mesos-slave log shows that:

```
I1223 15:38:40.822557 258486272 docker.cpp:761] Starting container 'ea1ed2fa-c2e3-469a-bcc4-142e0a6c624d' for task '2-1.2fb839ea-a948-11e5-9c42-2e7bf2aa25a6' (and executor '2-1.2fb839ea-a948-11e5-9c42-2e7bf2aa25a6') of framework '13165a00-8e58-4d80-b84d-fe4652022a3e-0000'
E1223 15:38:41.219044 254730240 slave.cpp:3342] Container 'ea1ed2fa-c2e3-469a-bcc4-142e0a6c624d' for executor '2-1.2fb839ea-a948-11e5-9c42-2e7bf2aa25a6' of framework '13165a00-8e58-4d80-b84d-fe4652022a3e-0000' failed to start: Failed to 'docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock pull python:3': exit status = exited with status 1 stderr = An error occurred trying to connect: Post https:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.19/images/create?fromImage=python%3A3: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory
```

from that,  i can see mesos-slave excute `docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock pull python:3`  to download images.

but I use Mac OSX,  And the docker is running in the vm , 
So there is no `docker.sock` file in my slave but the vm.

How cuold i solve the issue on Mac OSX? please help me ,thanks!

Comment: So, you're running Mesos natively on Mac OS? And Docker is running with docker-machine?

Comment: i just use boot2docker ,   not the docker-machine ,   do you have any idea for me  ?, thanks

Comment: Mesos Master and Slave is also started via boot2docker? If so, you'll need to pass in the Docker socket as volume. Have a look at https://github.com/tobilg/coreos-setup/blob/master/etc/systemd/system/mesos-slave.service#L18

Comment: no ,  I  run master and slave on my host,  i boot all the things  on only one machine

Comment: my ip is 192.168.168.128 , so the master and slave ip is 192.168.168.128,       but boot2docker vm ip is 192.168.59.103, when mesos-slave create docker container , it will excute `docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock pull`,  but my os is not linux,  the file `docker.socke` is in my boot2docker vm ,  so it failed

Comment: @KingOfSocket you can pass `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2375` environment variable when starting mesos-slave by using `--executor_environment_variables` more info [here](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/)
Check if that resolves the issue

Comment: @V.G  I start mesos with `--executor_environment_variables`  and set the `DOCKER_HOST` ,  but the it told me the same error ....

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too.  I was trying to run zookeeper, mesos, marathon, and friends all in one docker-compose file with my mac.

Trying to run things in marathon would cause the exact error that you got.  I discovered that the docker daemon was not running on the slave.  All I had to do was start it: `docker exec <mesos-slave-container-name> sudo service docker start`.

From then on, I was able to run docker containers using marathon.